# Increase most visited page display in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I want to display more `Most Visited` pages in google chrome, currently only 9 pages are being displayed, how can I increase them to 12 or 20 ??

Comment: I see there's an issue open on the subject in the Chromium google code project:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27704

Comment: Too bad `laforge@chromium.org` closed the request as **won’t fix**.

Comment: It is not nice, but you can edit the chrome.dll on your own: http://www.maxrev.de/google-chrome-most-visited-meistbesucht-mehr-vorschaubilder-t264643.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Dev Channel](http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel) build of Chrome does offer [a more customisable New Tab Page](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/06/chrome-tests-updated-new-tab-page.html) but this doesn't allow you to change the number of thumbnails.

So I don't think you can change the number of pages you see.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone is still looking for this functionality, you can use Speed Dial extension for Chrome. However, I have not yet found a way to use the most visited websites automatically.

https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dgpdioedihjhncjafcpgbbjdpbbkikmi

Comment: Just to make it clear, for anyone unfamiliar with Speed Dial, you have to manually choose the sites -- despite the assumptions of some chromium developers, it's not an equivalent replacement for the Most Visited sites feature.

Comment: The one thing that makes me suspicious, all this extensions require "access all data on you pages" permissions, which seems fishily.

Answer (score 2):

There *may* be a way to do this by writing an extension (I have not seen any yet though).

There's a [topSites API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/topSites.html#type-MostVisitedURL) that gives access to the Titles and URLs of the "Most Visited" pages (I think currently only 20 are tracked).

The thumbnails *may* be available via `chrome://thumb/URL`. I'm not sure if you can actually access the thumbs from extensions though.